# How can I use a key other than <ENTER> to exit zsh's completion menu/widget?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Like a lot of zsh users, I have completion configured so that when I am at a command prompt and I invoke completion, a menu appears that can be navigated with the directional arrow keys. i.e. in my `~/.zshrc`

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' menu yes select
zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*' menu yes select
```

If I want to delete the directory `/var/log/nginx/somewebsite`,  I will start the command using completion like:

```
ubuntu% sudo rm -rf /var/l<TAB>
lib/    local/  lock@   log/
```

I navigate the items with the directional arrow keys, which are inserted into the command line as the cursor moves over them; once on the desired selection, hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> basically to exit the menu widget and return the cursor back to the command line.
The problem is <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is used for both accepting the item from the completion menu and also executing the command, and I keep hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> thinking I am accepting completion when I am actually executing these partially complete commands!

Can I remap zsh's "accept completion suggestion and exit widget" command to something other than <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?
e.g. <kbd>TAB</kbd> or even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> (same as vim's accept completion keymap)

Comment: Which version are you using? My zsh 5.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) works as expected - first enter accepts completion, second accepts/executes command line.

Answer (score 1):

I found the documentation for this in

- `man zshmodules`

  - THE ZSH/COMPLIST MODULE

    - menu selection

To bind the key <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd></kbd> to accept a completion suggestion, you can use

```
bindkey ^Y accept-search
```

There is a note in the documentation

> Note that the following *(complist functions)* always perform the  same  task
>          within  the  menu  selection map and cannot be replaced by user defined
>          widgets, nor can the set of functions be extended:

so accordingly,  you can't unbind <kbd>Enter</kbd> away from `accept-search`, in fact funnily enough the command

```
bindkey -r ^M accept-search
```

only succeeds in *unbinding* `accept-line` from a normal command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind another key to accept a completion suggestion so that it's only active during menu-completion: `bindkey -M menuselect <key> accept-search` (assuming you use menu-completion).

Also, if you want <kbd>Enter</kbd> to immediately execute the command line, rather than having to press it twice to first accept the completion: `bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line`